# How to create a new SharedPreferences if the key is taken?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have a code that I'm using to store calendar event/date information. I want to be able to call for multiple dates/events, but so far I can only store one or it overwrites. Stored____ is the name of each day, month, year, etc I get from my CalendarView. The onSelectedDayChange checks that if there is a date that corrosponds to the date selected on the phone, and it outputs all of the info in a Snackbar.  My code is as follows:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("savedevent",EventView.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("savedyear", storedyear);
    editor.putInt("savedmonth", storedmonth);
    editor.putInt("savedday", storedday);
    editor.putInt("savedhour", storedhour);
    editor.putInt("savedminute", storedminute);
    editor.commit();
    editor.apply();
    finish();
```

---

```
   final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                        int dayOfMonth) {
            if (year == prefs.getInt("savedyear",0) && month == prefs.getInt("savedmonth",0) && dayOfMonth == prefs.getInt("savedday",0)){
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout), "Event: " + prefs.getString("savedevent",null) + " Date: " + (prefs.getInt("savedmonth", 0) + 1) + "/" + prefs.getInt("savedday", 0) + "/" + prefs.getInt("savedyear", 0) + " Time: " + prefs.getInt("savedhour", 0) + ":" + prefs.getInt("savedminute", 0), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Can someone help explain to me how I would be able to store multiple events so when a date is clicked, all of them would be able to display and they wouldn't overwrite each other?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store multiple events, you should not use `SharedPreferences`. Instead, you should create an SQLite database to store the data.

Create a table called `Events` and add columns like "Name", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour" and "Minute". Then you can get data from and save data to the database.

If you know SQL, this method will be very easy for you to implement. But if you are someone who knows little SQL, like me, I recommend you to use an ORM library to help you with the database.

IMO, [SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) is a very user-friendly ORM library. Just create a class called `Event` that extends `SugarRecord<Event>` and you can easily fetch data and save data without any SQL!

If you are lazy, here's the class:

```
public class Event extends SugarRecord<Event> {
    public String name;
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;
    public int hour;
    public int minute;

    public Event() { }
    public Event(String name, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
    }
}
```

You can get all the events you saved by:

```
Event.listAll(Event.class);
```

You can save an event by calling:

```
Event e = new Event("Some Stuff", 2016, 4, 10, 11, 8);
e.save();
```

Super Easy!

Comment: In the link I gave you, it has all the details you need to know about SugarORM. See the "Query Builder" section. @Yep